# Adding the sum of positive and negative integer in the array c# for loop

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

The part ""The sum of positive input is :" and "The sum of negative input is :" are not working there's no answer showing what could be the solution? btw this an 11th grade question

```
int i, num, sum = 0;
Console.Write("\nInput the number of elements to be stored in the array :");
num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Elements - {0}:", i, num);
    array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
Console.Write("The positive inputs are :");
for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    if (array[i] >= 0)
    {

        Console.Write(array[i] + ",");
        array[i]++;


    }
}
Console.Write("\nThe sum of positive input is :");
for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    if (array[i] >= 0)
    {
        sum += array[i];
    }
}
    Console.Write("\nThe negative inputs are :");
for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    if (array[i] < 0)
    {
        Console.Write(array[i] + ",");
        array[i]++;

    }
}
Console.Write("\nThe sum of negative input is :");
for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    if (array[i] < 0)
    {
        sum += array[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("The sum is " +sum)` ? You simply didn't print the sum.. Shouldn't you reset the sum before suming the negative value? Or do you need to windraw the negative value from the sum of positives values? perhaps you can loop on this array only once?Is it normal that you incremente the value just after displaying them?

Comment: i added the +sum but it gives a wrong answer

Comment: You did it after the compuation right?

Comment: First of all, you haven't added code to display sum, so after sum-calculating for-loop ends you need to add something like this `Console.WriteLine(sum);`. Second, after sum of positive numbers is calculated, you have to make `sum = 0` to get exact output for negative numbers as required.

Comment: Btw do you understand what `array[i]++;` does? You have it in every "_The negative inputs are_" and "_The positive inputs are_". It change the value of the array by adding one to it. So just after display the value, you change it.

Comment: i already removed the array[i]++; thank you

Comment: Hi sir Usama i added the console.writeline(sum); it gives an accurate answer i input 2 and 6 and it gives "08" how can i make it 8 only and how to make the sum = 0 where part should i put it

Comment: How can i remove the "0" from the sum in the negative it gives me 0-6

Comment: btw Sirs thank you i already solve the problem the reason why it has "0" because of the ("The sum is " +sum)

Answer (score 0):

Special thanks to Sir Usama And Sir Drag and Drop

```cs
int[] array = new int[100];
int i, num, sum = 0;

Console.Write("\nInput the number of elements to be stored in the array :");
num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Elements - {0}:", i, num);
    array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}

Console.Write("The positive inputs are :");
for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    if (array[i] >= 0)
    {
        Console.Write(array[i] + ",");
    }
}

Console.Write("\nThe sum of positive input is :" );
for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    if (array[i] >= 0)
    {
        sum += array[i];
    }
}

Console.Write(sum);
sum = 0;
Console.Write("\nThe negative inputs are :");
for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    if (array[i] < 0)
    {
        Console.Write(array[i] + ",");
    }
}

Console.Write("\nThe sum of negative input are :" );
for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    if (array[i] < 0)
    {
        sum += array[i];
    }
}

Console.Write(sum);
```

Comment: After filling the array move every `Console.Write` to the end. And for every similar For loop copy and past the core instruction. You can do all this in only one loop Using a simple `if(input>=0){}else{}`, you will just need few variable to store both sum and both string representation of possitve/negative number.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't initialize your array after you read the array length from user input. You should have:

```cs
int[] array;
Console.Write("\nInput the number of elements to be stored in the array :");
num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
array = new int[num];
```

Second, you are using the same `sum` variable for both positive and negative calculation (without resetting it in between). You can use two separate variables for these two computations:

```cs
int i, num, posSum = 0, negSum = 0;
```

Third, as [Drag and Drop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6560478/drag-and-drop) mentioned in the comment, you don't need that `array[i]++;`, since it modifies the elements of the array.

Fourth, as [Usama Aziz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13976468/usama-aziz) mentioned in the comment, you don't have a `Console.Write` where you print the results.

The final solution should look like this:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i, num, posSum = 0, negSum = 0;
    int[] array;
    Console.Write("\nInput the number of elements to be stored in the array :");
    num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    array = new int[num];

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("Elements - {0}:", i, num);
        array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    Console.Write("The positive inputs are :");
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] >= 0)
        {
            Console.Write(array[i] + ",");
        }
    }

    Console.Write("\nThe sum of positive input is :");
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] >= 0)
        {
            posSum += array[i];
        }
    }
    Console.Write(posSum);

    Console.Write("\nThe negative inputs are :");
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] < 0)
        {
            Console.Write(array[i] + ",");
        }
    }

    Console.Write("\nThe sum of negative input is :");
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] < 0)
        {
            negSum += array[i];
        }
    }
    Console.Write(negSum);
}
```

Good luck on your exam!

Comment: hi sir in my first try i used  posSum = 0, negSum = 0; idk why it didnt work maybe i used it in a wrong way btw thank you sir!